# Is there a format to set thousand separator and also set two decimal places using Apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, number-formatting

I can either set thousand operator like this:

```
cell.getCellStyle().setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#,#00"));
```

Or set two decimal places:

```
cell.getCellStyle().setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("0.00"));
```

Is there an option to set both?

Comment: cell.getCellStyle().setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#,#00.00")); https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html

Comment: Have you tried `"#.##0,00"`? I think this depends on the locale... Could be the other way round as @Fullslack.dev commented.

Comment: @deHaar `#,##0.00` this worked for me. Thanks though

Comment: @NemJov good... Just a thing to keep in mind: In my German version of Excel, the one I posted is the working one (because a thousand separator is a dot and not a comma, while decimal places are behind a comma). So the **locale of Excel** matters.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
cell.getCellStyle().setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#,##0.00"));
```

Found solution based on @Fullslack.dev comment `https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html`